# Getting Apache Camel to stop retrying if failed to move the file after route completion

Tags: java, file-io, exception, locking, apache-camel

The example route below picks up a file and performs a series of operations on them. Once completed, as noted in the `camel:from` field, the route is instructed to move the file to a `.processed` directory. Alternatively if failed, move it to the `.error` folder.

The problem occurs when another process as a lock on the file (ie. excel) and camel is unable to move the file, therefore, it infinitely keeps retrying which is an undesired behaviour.

Adding a `retrypolicy` or `onException` will not solver this specific issue as I would not like to retry the entire route *but rather* retry the file move only

```
<camel:route id="aRoute">
    <camel:from
            uri="file://{{sourceFileLocation}}?include=fileToProcess.csv&amp;moveFailed=.error/$simple{date:now:yyyy}/$simple{date:now:MM}/$simple{date:now:dd}/$simple{file:name}&amp;move=.processed/$simple{date:now:yyyy}/$simple{date:now:MM}/$simple{date:now:dd}/$simple{file:name}"/>
    <camel:setHeader headerName="CATEGORY">
        <camel:constant>category a</camel:constant>
    </camel:setHeader>
    <camel:process ref="asOfDateService"/>
    <camel:process ref="batchIdService"/>
    <camel:process ref="aService"/>
    <camel:to uri="log:aRoute"/>
    <camel:process ref="factXLookup"/>
    <camel:process ref="factXConversionInsert"/>
    <camel:process ref="batchTableCleanupService"/>
    <camel:process ref="batchUpdateService"/>
    <camel:onException>
        <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
        <camel:process ref="batchFailedService"/>
    </camel:onException>
</camel:route>
```

For clarification purposes you can ignore the `onException` above as that is dealing with issues in the data integrity / quality of the process.

**TLDR**: How can I retry camel's file-move on completion without re-executing the entire route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that the File component needs to handle, not your route.

You can configure how the File component should handle locked files using the `readLock` option (along with other related options). The option has an extensive description on the [File2 component documentation page](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)